# How do i add simple jQuery to Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm having trouble getting my jQuery script to load on my wordpress website.. Iv'e added a js directory in the theme file  already. What am i missing or doing wrong?

```
function add_my_script() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'myscript', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', // this is the location of your script file
    array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script');`
```

Comment: Have you seen this CSS-Tricks post: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you include another script as a dependency and that script is not itself loaded then your script is not loaded either.  Can't remember if jquery is automatically.  Try the following:

```
<?php
function add_my_script() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script(
      'myscript', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', // this is the location of your script file
      array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
   );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script');`
```

The depency affects the order in which the scripts are loaded, it doesn't auto-load dependent scripts

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is a child theme, you will want to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() (template_directory_uri refers to the parent theme's directory)

If you are 100% sure your JS is being loaded by the browser, make sure you are using jQuery in noconflicts mode

example:   jQuery(document) instead of $(document)